# I Want to know what makes the text change? Css/Php

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a problem with my website. All of the button will redirect you to different pages Home(mypage.php) More About me(more.php) Contact me(Register.php)

I just want to know why the text change here below when I click the Contact me(Register.php)
[image: 1.png]

Other pages(It should be like this)

[image: 2.png]

They all have the same css script written below 
(style.css)

```
h1{color:yellow;}
h2{color: yellow;}
body{outline-style: dotted;outline-color: yellow;}
.r{font-family: verdana}
body {background-image: url("c.jpg");}
#h{border-radius: 50%;}
.1{border-radius: 20%;}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a  {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #111;
}

li a:hover{
 background-color: yellow;}

 #content2{
     margin-top: 100px;
     color:blue;
 }
```

register.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />
<style>
<?php include 'style.css'; ?>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'links.php';?>
<center>

<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5"><a href="add_data.php">add data here.</a></th>
    </tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>City Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Operations</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM users";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
  <td align="center"><a href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="edit.png" align="EDIT" /></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="delete.png" align="DELETE" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

style2.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body
{
 background:#f9f9f9;
 font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
#header
{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:#00a2d1;
 color:#f9f9f9;
 font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size:35px;
 text-align:center;
}
#header a
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:blink;
}
#body
{
 margin-top:50px;
}
table
{
 width:80%;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bolder;
 color:#999;
 margin-bottom:80px;
}
table a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#00a2d1;
}
table,td,th
{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border:solid #0000FF 1px;
 padding:20px;
}
table td input
{
 width:97%;
 height:35px;
 border:dashed #00a2d1 1px;
 padding-left:15px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
}
table td input:focus
{
 box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
}
table td button
{
 border:solid #f9f9f9 0px;
 box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
 background:#00a2d1;
 padding:9px 15px 9px 15px;
 color:#f9f9f9;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bolder;
 border-radius:3px;
 width:49.5%;
}
table td button:active
{
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

links.php

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="more.php">More about me</a></li>
<li><a href="Register.php">Contact me</a></li>
</ul>
```

add_data.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
 // variables for input data
 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
 $Nickname = $_POST['Nickname'];
 $Email = $_POST['Email'];
 $Phone_number = $_POST['Phone_number'];
 $Home_address = $_POST['Home_address'];
 // variables for input data

 // sql query for inserting data into database
 $sql_query = "INSERT INTO users(Name,Nickname,Email,Phone_number,Home_address) VALUES('$Name','$Nickname','$Phone_number',$'Home_address')";
 // sql query for inserting data into database

 // sql query execution function
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
 {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Data Are Inserted Successfully ');
  window.location.href='index.php';
  </script>
  <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('error occured while inserting your data');
  </script>
  <?php
 }
 // sql query execution function
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
<?php include 'style.css';?>
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Page :)</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'links.php';?>
<center>

<div id="header">
 <div id="content2">
    <label>Contact me</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
    <form method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Home_address" placeholder="Home Address" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button type="submit" name="btn-save"><strong>SAVE</strong></button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the code of more.php or mypage.php?

Comment: Also you are linking a second css sheet `style2.css` check that as well

Comment: Rather include your CSS file in your HTML using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: Can you post the code for `links.php`?

Comment: @Blinkydamo added

Comment: @k97513 added links.php

Comment: @Daniel_ZA wont work mate

Comment: Where is `#Header`? Is it not in the `register.php` page?

Comment: @k97513 header is in add_data.php

Comment: `style2.css` sets the `body` to `font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;` and `style.css` does not set a `font-family`. Register.php references `style2.css` and add_data.php does not so the have different font-familys

Comment: @zgood Thanks man!!!

Comment: @Ralph.D ok if that solved it I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet `style2.css` sets the body font to `font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;` and the stylesheet `style.css` does not set a body font.

Register.php references `style2.css` so its body font gets set to Courier New. add_data.php does not reference `style2.css` so its body font will default to Times New Roman.

This is why they have different fonts. To fix it either add `font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;` to the `body` style in `style.css` or remove that style from `style2.css`, depending on what font you want.